# LDAP return properties some of them are not given by me its not loading department property ? MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, ldap, activedirectorymembership

my code for getting AD specific user details is,

```
  SearchResultCollection results;
                    DirectorySearcher ds = null;
                    DirectoryEntry de = new
                         DirectoryEntry("LDAP://****");
                    SearchResult sr;

                    ds = BuildUserSearcher(de);

                    ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(|(&(SAMAccountName={0}*))))", model.User.Username.Trim());

                    sr = ds.FindOne();



 public DirectorySearcher BuildUserSearcher(DirectoryEntry de)
    {
        DirectorySearcher ds = null;

    ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department"); 
    // Full Name
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
    // Email Address
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");
    // First Name
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
    // Last Name (Surname)

    // Login Name
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");
    // Distinguished Name
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");

    return ds;
}
```

Code is working and returning values but not as required it is returning me these properties,

```
"distinguishedname"
"userprincipalname"
"givenname"
"sn"
"name"
"adspath"
```

It is not returning properties from method and i must need department ? Any idea

i have adspath value like

```
""LDAP://CN=John cena,OU=Developers,OU=IT Department,OU=Users Acounts,DC=Mumbai,DC=Local""
```

Is there any way to get it from this  url  "`OU=IT Department`"

Hopes for your suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does that AD account have a value in the `department` attribute? If the attribute is empty, it will not appear in the `Properties` collection at all. That is normal.

So you will have to use `sr.Properties.Contains("department")` to check if the value is there before you try to use it.

A side point: your `BuildUserSearcher` can be simplified to this:

```
public DirectorySearcher BuildUserSearcher(DirectoryEntry de)
{
    return new DirectorySearcher(de) {
        PropertiesToLoad = {
            "department",
            "name",              // Full Name
            "mobile",            // Email Address
            "givenname",         // First Name
            "userPrincipalName", // Login Name
            "distinguishedName", // Distinguished Name
            "sn"                 // Last Name (Surname)
        }
    };
}
```

No difference in functionality, it's just shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

The property name 'distinguished**n**ame' should be in small caps instead of 'distinguishedName'. Like 'givenname' is already working for you not 'givenName'.